# Remove click event handler immediately after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I've been trying to remove the click event handler after being clicked once to prevent the event from firing multiple times.

I've tried `.unbind()`, `.off()`, `.one()` and put each in various different places in the function, but none seem to work.

If I use `.off()` I get a `undefined is not a function` error.

If I use `.one()` I want to basically turn the event back on if I click the other button.  So if I click on select, I want it to only fire once, but if I then click on unselect, I want select to be clickable again.

I've tried doing the following, but oddly the code doesn't even fire, and so I've been forced to use `click()`.

```
$().on('click', function()...
```

Which function should I use and where should I put it?

```
(function($) {

Drupal.behaviors.wysiwyg = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {

        var toggle = function(state) {
            $('#wysiwyg-profile-form .buttons-and-plugins input:checkbox').attr('checked', state);
        }

        $('#wysiwyg-select-all').click(function(){
    toggle(true);
            return false;
        });

        $('#wysiwyg-unselect-all').click(function(){
    toggle(false);
            return false;
        });
    }
}

}(jQuery))
```

Comment: _If I use .off() I get a undefined is not a function error._ Which version of jQuery you are using?

Comment: We can't tell you what's wrong with your use of `.off()` or `.one()` unless you share that code, too.

Comment: Do you later want to click the same button? If all you're doing is trying to make sure a user does not inadvertently click twice, you can disable the button immediately after the click and then enable it upon setTimeout of say 5 seconds. Even if two clicks came together so fast, only the first would register.

Comment: He's binding the click with the .click(), not on(). That's why off() isn't working.

Comment: @aecend Then how do I unbind `click()`.

Comment: @Kevin, see my answer below. Use `.on("click", function(){})` instead of `.click(function(){})`. Once you've done that, you'll be able to use `.off("click")`

Comment: @aecend See my update above.  `.on('click', function(){})` Is oddly not working.  The event doesn't even fire.

Comment: Is this a dynamically created element?

Comment: If you would rather not hassle with having to rebind the events, take a look at the answer I've posted. It sets a variable with the element that was clicked and only allows the event to fire once until the other button is clicked.

Comment: If it is a dynamically created element, then it's likely that .on() isn't firing because the element is being created after the event binding. Is that the case?

Comment: That would make sense.  Which would also explain why I am getting the undefined error.

Comment: Dynamically created element typically have the event handlers attached when you create the element, but because you need it to be removed and then added again attach the `.on` event to the document itself. See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this works for you. Also make sure the jquery version is above 1.7 for "on", "off" to work.

```
(function($) {

  Drupal.behaviors.wysiwyg = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
    var counter = 0;
      var toggle = function(state) {
        $('#wysiwyg-profile-form .buttons-and-plugins input:checkbox').attr('checked', state);
      }

      $(document).off('click',"#wysiwyg-select-all").on('click', "#wysiwyg-select-all", function(e) {
        toggle(true);               
        return false;
      });

      $(document).off('click',"#wysiwyg-unselect-all").on('click', "#wysiwyg-unselect-all", function(e) {
        toggle(false);      
        return false;
      });
    }
  }

}(jQuery))
```

Comment: Thanks for asking if my jQuery version was above 1.7.  I realized that in fact, my version was too low.  Once I updated to 1.9 I no longer got the undefined error for `.on('click')` and so now the `.off()` `.on()` works.  I like the chaining in this case so I'll give it to you.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**

I was messing around with a couple of the things these other guys were suggesting and I think this is exactly what you need to accomplish this:

```
(function ($) {

    Drupal.behaviors.wysiwyg = {
        attach: function (context, settings) {

            var selectFn = function() {
                toggle(true);
                return false;
            }

            var unselectFn = function() {
                toggle(false);
                return false;
            }    

            var toggle = function (state) {
                $('#wysiwyg-profile-form .buttons-and-plugins input:checkbox').attr('checked', state);
                if (state) {
                    $(document).off("click", '#wysiwyg-select-all,#wysiwyg-unselect-all', "**");
                    $(document).on("click", "#wysiwyg-unselect-all", unselectFn;
                }else{
                    $(document).off("click", '#wysiwyg-select-all,#wysiwyg-unselect-all', "**");
                    $(document).on("click", "#wysiwyg-select-all", selectFn;
                }
            };

            $(document).on("click", "#wysiwyg-select-all", selectFn);
            $(document).on("click", "#wysiwyg-unselect-all", unselectFn);

        }
    };

}(jQuery));
```

It toggles the binding of the buttons events and will work with dynamically created elements. This is a derivative of Matt Green's answer, but I noticed several problems with his, namely that he was calling the selectFn and unselectFn in his event binding rather than referencing them.

Comment: The second did not work for me... it still goes into the loop.

Comment: @Kevin, I made a change to the way it stores the reference and moved the variable into the global scope. Would you mind trying it?

Comment: I did what you said, and it no longer hits the `toggle(true)`, however, that doesn't mean a click even still wasn't fired right?  It looks like the click event is still hit, but nothing happens when it gets hit.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$("#wysiwyg-select-all").one("click", function() {
    toggle(true);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I just updated my question, but if I use `.one()` I want the event to be fired again if the other event is fired.  Make sense?

Comment: so... rebind it? you're the one that said you wanted to unbind it.

Comment: I've tried rebinding it to no avail.  How would I do so in this case?  Create a wrapper function and then call it inside of the event?

Answer (score 0):

Add a class name to the click button and then remove the class once its clicked once.

```
$('#wysiwyg-select-all .myclassname').on('click', function(){
    toggle(true);
    $(this).removeClass('myclassname');
    $('#wysiwyg-unselect-all').addClass('secondclassname');
    return false;
});

$('#wysiwyg-unselect-all .secondclassname').on('click', function(){
    toggle(false);
    $('#wysiwyg-select-all').addClass('myclassname');
    $(this).removeClass('secondclassname');
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for dynamically created elements:

```
(function ($) {

    Drupal.behaviors.wysiwyg = {
        attach: function (context, settings) {

            var toggle = function (state) {
                $('#wysiwyg-profile-form .buttons-and-plugins input:checkbox').attr('checked', state);
            };

            $(document).on("click", "#wysiwyg-select-all", selectFn());
            $(document).on("click", "#wysiwyg-unselect-all", unselectFn());
        }
    };

}(jQuery));


function selectFn() {
    $(document).off("click", '#wysiwyg-select-all', "**");
    $(document).on("click", "#wysiwyg-unselect-all", unselectFn());
    toggle(true);
    return false;
}

function unselectFn() {
    $(document).off("click", '#wysiwyg-unselect-all', "**");
    $(document).on("click", "#wysiwyg-select-all", selectFn());
    toggle(false);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I tried this.  It throws the `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` error.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use any global variable as a flag. On click event set it true.

```
if (btn1Clicked)
     return;
btn1Clicked=true;
```

And to reenable just set it false. 
You can use return false instead of return if required.

Comment: "Why don't you use any global variable as a flag", because global variables should be avoided unless absolutely nessacary

Comment: @MattGreen and why is it so.

Comment: You can use globals if they are protected in what you think is a unique namespace and are only used when beneficial. The main issue is that globals can make one piece of code more likely to conflict with some other piece of code (if not using different namespaces or very unique names). For this reason and others, it is best to avoid globals when they are not actually needed.